# JavaScript - How to underline the first character of every word

Tags: javascript

Sentence: Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.

JavaScript Code:
`

```
function myFunction(){
var str = document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML;
for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++){
if(i == 0 )
  {
      var res = str.replace(str.charAt(i+1), "<u>"+str.charAt(i+1)+"</u>");
      document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = res;
  }else if(str.charAt(i) == " ")
    {
        var res = str.replace(str.charAt(i+1), "<u>"+str.charAt(i+1)+"</u>");
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = res;
    }
}`
```

Problem: I am trying to underline the first character in every word of a paragraph when a button is pressed. With the code I have only the C from car is underlined. if anyone can see where I have gone wrong or if there is a better way of doing this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Your replace is not working the way you think, it will replace the first occurrence of given character and not necesarily the one you are looking at. `str.replace(' '+str.charAt(i+1), ...)` should be a reasonable workaround. There is also a nice solution using regexes, maybe I'll add it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working partially correct. It works on every word of the string but is getting updated again with next word.

You can make it simple by using a regex.

```
str.replace(/([^\s]+)/g,function(str){ 
    return "<u>"+str.charAt(0)+"</u>" + str.slice(1);
})
```

Explanation of the regex:

> **(**: Capturing group start
>
> **[^**: Negated set - Match anything which is not in the set.
>
> **\s**: Matches any whitespace character (spaces)
>
> **]**: set ends
>
> **)**: Capturing group ends

Looking at the syntax of the javascript replace function:

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)
```

> function (replacement)
>
> A function to be invoked to create the new substring to be used to
>   replace the matches to the given regexp or substr. The arguments
>   supplied to this function are **match**, submatch, offset and the
>   original string. (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter))

Edit: You are still not using the accepted solution in your answer properly. This is how your function will look now:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML;
    var result = str.replace(/([^\s]+)/g,function(str){
        return "<u>"+str.charAt(0)+"</u>" + str.slice(1);
    });
    document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
```

and if you are comfortable with ES6:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        const str = document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML;
        const result = str.replace(/([^\s]+)/g, p1 => `<u>${p1.charAt(0)}</u>${p1.slice(1)}` );
        document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML = result;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can make it simpler using word boundary match and new ES6 syntax: ```str.replace(/\b[^\s]/g, c => `<u>${c}</u>`)```. The regex might also be `/\b\w/g` to match only alphanumeric characters, it's tad bit easier to read and may have actually more desirable effect.

Comment: Your regex made it whole simpler. 
You took the positive approach (taking out all words), I took the negation approach (taking out everything which is not spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You store the mutation inside `res`, but you don't update `str`, so at the next iteration the previous changes get discarded. Instead just mutate `str`:

```
 str = str.replace(str.charAt(i+1), "<u>"+str.charAt(i+1)+"</u>");
```

And then after the loop is done reflect it to the DOM once:

```
 document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = str;
```

---

How i would solve that:

```
   function underline(selector) {
      const el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      let result = "";
      for(const word of el.innerHTML.split(" ")) {
        result += `<u>${word[0]}</u>${word.substr(1)}`;
      }
      el.innerHtML = result;
  }

 underline("#sentence");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML;
var words = str.match(/\S*/g);
var words2 = [];
words.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
   if (item!="") 
   {
      words2.push(item.replace(item.charAt(1), "<u>"+item.charAt(1)+"</a>"));
   }
});
document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = words2.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help, greatly appreciated.

Full Solutions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="Sentence">Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML;

  var res = str.replace(/([^\s]+)/g,function(str){
    return "<u>"+str.charAt(0)+"</u>" + str.slice(1);
});
      document.getElementById("Sentence").innerHTML = res;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You actually din't understand the accepted solution completely. This code will work but it has a lot of unnecessary code. Let me update the accepted solution with your requirements.